# Retrieve data in MySQL and display it in calendar control VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, calendar

I am targeting to create a Scheduling System in VB.Net and I am using Calendar Control, before I will ask my question, Let me explain to you first what scenario I would like to happen.

I have a form in VB.Net and it looks like this.

[image]

and here is my database

[image]

and fields of the table above are.

```
RefID
PersonName
DateSchedule (DateField)
```

Now here is my question. How can I display those data in my Calendar Control? like this (Example)

[image]

How can I achieve this kind of output? Regardless of how many data I will input it will Group the Data by Date and display it in the Calendar.

Lets say I will input data in Jun 6 so the calendar will Display Data from Jun 4 and 6.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is in the SQL query and/or how you use it

Comment: As of now, I didn`t do nothing yet. Please help me

Comment: If you enter June 6, the data need to fetch from the first day of the month to the input date?

Comment: Yes Sir, the List of Person will Show in each date based on the Data in Database

Comment: For Example Person 1 and Person 2 is Listed in the Jun 7 2016 so the Names will show in the Calendar. Like the Image in my Post

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need not grouping the data. Apply where clause and fetch all the data and based on the result, you can load the data into the calendar control

```
SELECT @TestDate := '2016-06-06';

SELECT PersonName, DateSchedule
FROM TestingTable
WHERE DATE(DateSchedule) <= DATE(@TestDate)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28fbd/7