# Transfer data from one table to another if data doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 2 Tables in MySQL and they are:

[image]

As what you see on the Image above the The First 4 Rows of the Field `Item Code` of the Tables `General Inventory` and `Purchase Order` are the Same and the 5th row in the table `Purchase Order` are not in the table `General Inventory`. Now my Question is how can I achieve this? (Image Below)

[image]

as what you see on the Image above the Data from the field `Quantity` of Tables `General Inventory` and `Purchase Order` has been SUM because there preceding data under field `Item Code` is same and the Last one that has no equal value in the `General Inventory` table has been added.

**Let me Shorten Up the Question.**

How can I Sum Up the Data from the field `Quantity` of `Purchase Order` in the `General Quantity` if there Data in the `Item Code` field are the same else add the new data if the Data from `Purchase Order` doesn't exist in `General Inventory`.

I tried this code.

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory GI
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrder PO ON GI.ItemCode = PO.ItemCode AND GI.`Description` = PO.`Description` AND GI.Quantity = PO.Quantity  
SET GI.Quantity = GI.Quantity + PO.Quantity
```

and the Output is this

[image]

Now I tried the Second Code

```
INSERT INTO GeneralInventory (ItemCode, `Description`, Quantity)
SELECT PO.ItemCode, PO.`Description`, PO.Quantity
FROM PurchaseOrder PO
LEFT JOIN GeneralInventory GI ON GI.ItemCode = PO.ItemCode AND GI.`Description` = PO.`Description` AND GI.Quantity = PO.Quantity
WHERE GI.ItemCode IS NULL
```

the output is this.

[image]

The data has been Repeated instead the the `Item 5` will be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using `LEFT JOIN` you can get inserted the not matching rows into the GeneralInventory table

```
INSERT INTO GeneralInventory (ItemCode, `Description`, Quantity)
SELECT PO.ItemCode, PO.`Description`, PO.Quantity
FROM PurchaseOrder PO
LEFT JOIN GeneralInventory GI ON GI.ItemCode = PO.ItemCode AND GI.`Description` = PO.`Description` AND GI.Quantity = PO.Quantity
WHERE GI.ItemCode IS NULL
```

Then you can UPDATE the GeneralInventory's Quantity value with JOINing the tables

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory GI
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrder PO ON GI.ItemCode = PO.ItemCode AND GI.`Description` = PO.`Description` AND GI.Quantity = PO.Quantity  
SET GI.Quantity = GI.Quantity + PO.Quantity
```

Comment: Is it ok to use Initials of the field sir? Why you use PO and GI? is it ok to use that?

Comment: You mean Sir is that I will use this 2 MYSQL Command i will run both of them?

Comment: Yes, you can use those 2 commands to achieve your expectations. More over those are not initials, those are called as [ALIASES](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php). I used the table aliases for better readability.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much Sir, I will approve this Sir once I tried it Sir. TYSM in advance

Comment: Sir its Reverse the `General Inventory` table must the table that will be updated

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer. Please try with the recent `update` query.

Comment: Sir I`m done trying your Codes and Please kindly wait I will update my Post.

Comment: My bad, the update query executes and `Quantity` value is revised that causes the duplicates. Could you change the order. First execute the `INSERT INTO` then execute `UPDATE`

Comment: Okay Sir Let me try this and I will Update you again

Comment: All I can say Sir is Wow! TYSM. I will approve your answer.

Comment: Sir I have a 1 minor Question, When it comes in Bulk Data`s is this the Advisable Command I can use? Lets say I will use this command using Thousands of Data?

Comment: Thousands of records are not huge data, you can use these commands for that.

Comment: Oh, I get it now Sir Thank you so Much for a Big Help

Comment: Please help me with this one, If it is Okay with you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626637/retrieve-data-in-mysql-and-display-it-in-calendar-control-vb-net